# How to read a webpage table using requests-html?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests-html

I am new to python and am trying to parse a table from the given website into a PANDAS DATAFRAME.

I am using modules requests-html, requests, and beautifulSoup.

Here is the website, I would like to gather the table from:
https://www.aamc.org/data-reports/workforce/interactive-data/active-physicians-largest-specialties-2019

## MWE

```py
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.aamc.org/data-reports/workforce/interactive-data/active-physicians-largest-specialties-2019'

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# soup.find_all('table')
pages = soup.find('div', {'class': 'data-table-wrapper'})
df = pd.read_html(pages) # PROBLEM: somehow this table has no data
df.head()
```

Another attempt:

```py
import requests_html

sess = requests_html.HTMLSession()
res = sess.get(url)
page = res.html
import requests_html

sess = requests_html.HTMLSession()
res = sess.get(url)
page_html = res.html

df = pd.read_html(page_html.raw_html)
df # This gives dataframe, but has no Values
```

The screenshot is given below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page is embedded inside `<script>` in form of JavaScript. You can use `selenium` or parse the data manually from the page. I'm using [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) module to decode the data:

```py
import re
import js2py
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.aamc.org/data-reports/workforce/interactive-data/active-physicians-largest-specialties-2019"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"(?s)\$scope\.schools = (.*?);", html_doc).group(1)
data = [{k: v.strip() for k, v in d.items()} for d in js2py.eval_js(data)]

columns = {
    "specialty": "Specialty",
    "one": "Total Active Physicians",
    "two": "Patient Care",
    "three": "Teaching",
    "four": "Research",
    "five": "Other",
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns=columns)
print(df[list(columns.values())].to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Specialty | Total Active Physicians | Patient Care | Teaching | Research | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Specialties | 938,980 | 816,922 | 12,475 | 12,632 | 96,951 |
| Allergy and Immunology | 4,900 | 4,221 | 54 | 268 | 357 |
| Anatomic/Clinical Pathology | 12,643 | 8,711 | 385 | 520 | 3,027 |
| Anesthesiology | 42,267 | 39,377 | 540 | 180 | 2,170 |
| Cardiovascular Disease | 22,521 | 20,430 | 299 | 573 | 1,219 |
| Child and Adolescent Psychiatry | 9,787 | 8,670 | 134 | 109 | 874 |
| Critical Care Medicine | 13,093 | 11,146 | 178 | 111 | 1,658 |
| Dermatology | 12,516 | 11,747 | 100 | 98 | 571 |
| Emergency Medicine | 45,202 | 41,466 | 469 | 94 | 3,173 |
| Endocrinology, Diabetes, and Metabolism | 7,994 | 6,439 | 155 | 533 | 867 |
| Family Medicine/General Practice | 118,198 | 108,984 | 1,614 | 251 | 7,349 |
| Gastroenterology | 15,469 | 14,007 | 186 | 289 | 987 |
| General Surgery | 25,564 | 21,949 | 259 | 137 | 3,219 |
| Geriatric Medicine | 5,974 | 5,029 | 105 | 106 | 734 |
| Hematology and Oncology | 16,274 | 13,506 | 250 | 871 | 1,647 |
| Infectious Disease | 9,687 | 7,448 | 287 | 701 | 1,251 |
| Internal Medicine | 120,171 | 105,736 | 1,409 | 1,447 | 11,579 |
| Internal Medicine/Pediatrics | 5,509 | 4,924 | 74 | 28 | 483 |
| Interventional Cardiology | 4,407 | 3,956 | 22 | 6 | 423 |
| Neonatal-Perinatal Medicine | 5,919 | 5,008 | 135 | 175 | 601 |
| Nephrology | 11,407 | 9,964 | 140 | 316 | 987 |
| Neurological Surgery | 5,748 | 5,246 | 52 | 32 | 418 |
| Neurology | 14,146 | 11,896 | 245 | 629 | 1,376 |
| Neuroradiology | 4,089 | 3,496 | 63 | 7 | 523 |
| Obstetrics and Gynecology | 42,720 | 39,825 | 499 | 195 | 2,201 |
| Ophthalmology | 19,312 | 17,859 | 147 | 126 | 1,180 |
| Orthopedic Surgery | 19,069 | 18,097 | 120 | 57 | 795 |
| Otolaryngology | 9,777 | 9,140 | 90 | 23 | 524 |
| Pain Medicine and Pain Management | 5,871 | 5,459 | 38 | 9 | 365 |
| Pediatric Anesthesiology (Anesthesiology) | 2,571 | 2,127 | 47 | 4 | 393 |
| Pediatric Cardiology | 2,966 | 2,414 | 74 | 64 | 414 |
| Pediatric Critical Care Medicine | 2,639 | 2,118 | 78 | 20 | 423 |
| Pediatric Hematology/Oncology | 3,079 | 2,251 | 77 | 210 | 541 |
| Pediatrics | 60,618 | 54,764 | 844 | 663 | 4,347 |
| Physical Medicine and Rehabilitation | 9,767 | 8,920 | 69 | 38 | 740 |
| Plastic Surgery | 7,317 | 6,938 | 55 | 20 | 304 |
| Preventive Medicine | 6,675 | 4,218 | 146 | 457 | 1,854 |
| Psychiatry | 38,792 | 33,776 | 562 | 735 | 3,719 |
| Pulmonary Disease | 5,106 | 4,490 | 138 | 296 | 182 |
| Radiation Oncology | 5,306 | 4,854 | 56 | 33 | 363 |
| Radiology and Diagnostic Radiology | 28,025 | 24,748 | 423 | 153 | 2,701 |
| Rheumatology | 6,265 | 5,333 | 108 | 255 | 569 |
| Sports Medicine | 2,897 | 2,624 | 20 | 4 | 249 |
| Sports Medicine (Orthopedic Surgery) | 2,903 | 2,737 | 9 |  | 157 |
| Thoracic Surgery | 4,479 | 4,105 | 45 | 40 | 289 |
| Urology | 10,201 | 9,593 | 76 | 39 | 493 |
| Vascular and Interventional Radiology | 3,877 | 3,425 | 27 | 3 | 422 |
| Vascular Surgery | 3,943 | 3,586 | 48 | 13 | 296 |

Comment: This is great! Never heard of js2py.  Thanks a lot and Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Will you also give few comments on regex:  `re.search(r"(?s)\$scope\.schools = (.*?);"` that would be great.

Comment: @dallascow If you look at the HTML source code of the page `Ctrl+U` and search for "$scope.schools" you will see what data needs to be ectracted: everything from `[` to `];`. (?s) means i'm using `flags=re.S` - the dot matches the newline.

Comment: Got it. (also, (?s) is new to me. Used flags like re.M, re.I, re.S but not (?s), I thought it might be some kind of lookaround cases.

Comment: I am profoundly sorry for XY question, but is there a way parsing the table using installing js2py module and using only bs4 module. I have been able to see the table numbers but could not make it pandas dataframe:     `ifile = r'aamc/Active Physicians in the Largest Specialties, 2019 _ AAMC.html'
with open(ifile) as fh:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fh, 'html.parser')  
pages = soup.find('div', {'class': 'data-table-wrapper'})
df = pd.read_html(pages)`

Comment: I have simply saved the whole webpage in a folder `aamc` and tried to parse it using padas.

Comment: I think indirectly you already gave a hint. The regex should be able to extract the dictionary from given soup. Nevermind, Thanks.